# How do I find a group of words (boundary of words) using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have stored the contents of a text-file in a string called `Str` that looks like this:

```
Str = "Cat is an animal\n" +
      "Cat is small\n" +
      "Cat is a pet\n";
```

I've written this code to search for the word `Cat`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bCat\\b)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(Str);

while (match.find()) {
    String tempStr = "I found " + match.group() + "\n";
}
```

The above produces this output:

```
I found Cat
I found Cat 
I found Cat
```

Here is my question. How do I find the whole sentence by using the keyword Cat so that the output will be:

```
I found Cat is an animal
I found Cat is small
I found Cat is a pet
```

What is the Regular expression for this?

Comment: What have you tried? You haven't shown any attempts/leads for finding the sentence. Also I would say this question lacks detail/context.

Comment: Yeah, I have found the solution for my problem. I tried the simple Regex Vlad L have suggested and it returned the output that matched my expectation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need word boundaries here, you can make it simple:

```
"(Cat.*?)/n"
```

and then get the result from `match.group(1)`

Comment: This one works out well for me. Thanks everyone here for the help :).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "sentence" (this is a very broad term that can be defined in different ways) means until next period (`.`), you can try with

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bCat\\b.*\\.)");
```

`.*`  0 or more of any character

`\\.` Period character

Comment: I have made a mistake in my question. Each sentence doesn't end with a period.

Comment: So now I understand each sentence ends with newline character (`\n`), is this correct? You should specifically clarify this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the word boundary to avoid matching words like `Catwoman`? If so you're almost already there.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\bCat\\b[^.]*\\."); 
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("a super Cat too cute to be true.\n" + 
                                "and an other Cat.\n" +
                                "but not thatCat nor Catwoman no no no.");
```

Will find the two first lines, but not the third.